# Simple, custom navigation between 4 view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I have *UIScrollView* which contains many following *Subscription View Controllers*. Each *Subscription View Controller* contains *Container View Controller*.

[image]

The target is to do a simple navigation between 4 *Views Controllers* at the right side.

Navigation logic:

- On **viewDidLoad** show first or second *View Controller* in **Container**
- When the user press a button on *View Controller* show the third *View Controller* in the **Container**

I tried to use *Segues* but this didn't work. The way to instantiate VCs to 
*Subscription View Controller* is not good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way I found is to create custom *Segue*.
[image]

1. Creating custom `UIStoryboardSegue`

   1. Go to **File** **->** **New** **->** **File...** and choose **Cocoa Class**

   [image]

   2. Create a new class from **UIStoryboardSegue**

   [image]

   3. Configurate **MySegue**

```swift
import UIKit

class NewSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

    //Call when performSegueWithIdentifier() called
    override func perform() {
        //ViewController segue FROM
        var sourceViewController: UIViewController = self.sourceViewController as! UIViewController
        //ViewController segue TO
        var destinationViewController: UIViewController = self.destinationViewController as! UIViewController
        //Parent ViewController - ContainerViewController
        var containerViewController: UIViewController = sourceViewController.parentViewController!

        //Setting destinationViewController
        containerViewController.addChildViewController(destinationViewController)
        destinationViewController.view.frame = sourceViewController.view.frame
        sourceViewController.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)

        //Do animation
        containerViewController.transitionFromViewController(sourceViewController,
            toViewController: destinationViewController,
            duration: 0.3,
            options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCrossDissolve,
            animations: nil, completion: { finished in
                //Delete sourceViewController
                sourceViewController.removeFromParentViewController()
                //Show destinationViewController
                destinationViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(containerViewController)
        })
    }
}
```

2. Go to your **Storyboard** file and do control drag from **ContainerViewController** to needed Controller and choose **Custom** in context menu

[image]

3.Click on created segue and configure them

[image]

4. Now you can call `performSegueWithIdentifier("SugueID", sender: self)` in your **ContainerViewController** or in other **ViewController**

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to switch the container views view...

```
@IBOutlet weak var container: UIView!
   var currentViewController:UIViewController?

//put the view did load method here.



    @IBAction func buttonPressed() {

//the storyboard file that the view is in.
        let storyboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)


// the container view you want to switch to.
   self.currentViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("containerViewStoryboardID") as? UIViewController


//switch the container view.
        self.addChildViewController(self.currentViewController!)

        self.container.addSubview(self.currentViewController!.view)

        self.currentViewController!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)


}
```

Comment: Emm, this is a bad idea because I need to delete subviews and I will have problems with switch from other VC.

Comment: I've used this many times, and it works well. What other solution are you looking for? Are you looking just to switch the entire VC?

Comment: Yes, I need to switch the entire VC to other. However the next VC should be able to switch himself to other VC. And don't forget about Data exchange